# Apache2 + nginx partially working

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

Until now I have always used the LAMP setup. However, it seems that nginx, when acting as a proxy in front of the apache2 improves the performance.

I followed the guide found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache). I only changed the root directory from
`root /var/www/;` to `root /var/www/projects/develop/`.

I am getting half of the page loaded and the nginx error.log writes:

```
2013/05/03 11:03:34 [error] 5761#0: *1 "/srv/www/hybridlogic/public_html/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: hybridlogic.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "develop.localhost" 2013/05/03 11:03:34 [error] 5761#0: *1 open() "/srv/www/hybridlogic/public_html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: hybridlogic.dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "develop.localhost"
```

Nginx configuration on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /var/www/; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com; 

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Do you see any misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running FPM, that's likely where your performance comes from, not just throwing another layer in front.

Read your error, you're missing a simple favico at "/srv/www/hybridlogic/public_html/favicon.ico".  It's a legitimate file not found if the file is indeed not there.  That said, it's a benign error.

Comment: You are correct. But there is no dir 'srv/www....'  onlye var/www. The problem is not the favicon.ico but the rest of the page that fails to load

Comment: If you're using Apache as your backend, make sure that Apache is validly serving traffic on your new port (8080).  If that's set and you've restarted nginx to make the config take effect, post your config.  I've found nginx logs to be very literal

Comment: you mean the apache config?

Comment: the nginx config -- if apache responds correctly when you hit it directly on port 8080, then it's doing it's job.